# Get array of posts based on custom field values

Tags: custom-field, query

I'm looking to pull up an array of posts based on custom field values:

```
function GetPrimaryLinks($product){
echo '<ul>';
$args = array( 
              'product' => $product, 
              'meta_key' => 'primary_link', 
              'meta_value' => array(
                                    'home', 
                                    'obj_handling', 
                                    'standalone_doc', 
                                    'advantages', 
                                    'weaknesses', 
                                    'top_comments') );
$primarylinks = get_posts( $args );
foreach ($primarylinks as $post) :  setup_postdata($post);
echo '<li><a href="'.the_permalink().'">'.the_title().'</a></li>';
endforeach;
echo '</ul>';
}
```

Therefore, I can reuse the function on various products to pull up the pages for 'Home', "Obj. Handling", etc. and only use one SQL query each time.

This script obviously doesn't work because it's looking for posts with an array of meta_values, but I'm wondering if there's a way to write the function in one SQL query, rather than breaking up the meta_values into individual queries.

Comment: Are you trying obtain all posts with all those meta values, or posts with at least one of them...?

Comment: @StephenHarris To clarify, one post would have primary_link=>'home', another would have primary_link=>'obj_handling', etc. The function would output a list of primary links based on those meta values. So, more of the latter but the post would have only one value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the **[meta_query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)** argument, and the `"IN"` option for the `"Compare"` operator.

Your query would look something like:

```
$args = array( 
      'product' => $product, 
      'meta_query' => array(
          array( 
              'key' => 'primary_link', 
              'value' => array(
                    'home', 
                    'obj_handling', 
                    'standalone_doc', 
                    'advantages', 
                    'weaknesses', 
                    'top_comments'
                    ),
              'compare' => 'IN' )
          )
      );
```

Comment: Doh, you beat me to it! It should be an array of arrays though. :)

Comment: Ah, yup! will fix ;)

Comment: For some reason, I thought I read that I should use WP_Query instead of get_posts?

Comment: @AlxVallejo No. Only for the 2nd query.

Comment: @AlxVallejo `get_posts` works just as well as `WP_Query` for something like this. `WP_Query` also calls `setup_postdata`, so that you can use template tags like `<?php the_title(); ?>` and so on. But if you call `setup_postdata` yourself, as you're doing, they're basically identical functions.

Comment: Thanks @goldenapples. Any idea how I would order the array of posts as specified in the meta_query values?

Comment: Ah, so what you're saying is you want posts with the meta value *home* to show 1st, then those with *obj_handling*, and so on? I don't think ordering by user-defined functions is possible directly through `WP_Query` yet... You could do it with a filter on `posts_orderby`, but it would make a very intensive and slow query. I would sort the posts in PHP using `usort()` after getting the array with `get_posts`. But I suppose it depends what you're doing with them and how many posts you expect the query to return.